# Flickering effect in video after adding Hue Correct strip modifier

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I made a video that was a knock off news report, with a person sitting in front of a city skyline reading up "news". This was filmed in a room with a projector, the projector displayed the skyline, and the news reporter was sitting in front of the projected image.

The video looked ok, but needed some color adjustment, which I did with the Hue Correct strip modifier. But when I rendered the final video as MPEG4/H.264 after this color adjustment, the resulting video had a lot of flickering in light areas of the skyline behind the reporter. There was none of this flickering through several iterations of rendering the video with the same settings, but without the color adjustment.

Why did I get this flickering, and how can I avoid it in the future?

Comment: It may have been an issue with the amount of correction you used. What id you do with the Hue Correct tool. Can you post a before and after image showing the effect of the strip. My guess is that you have exceeded the legal values for the encoder.

Comment: Why not use a green screen and introduce the skyline digitally afterwards? It's digitally projected anyways... Will get rid of any such trouble by setup.

Comment: @3pointedit I don't have a video available to share at the moment, but I can try to recreate at some point. In Hue Correct, from the default view with S selected, I pulled the second point from the left (in yellow area) straight down to the first horizontal grid line. The third point I pulled half as much down. I have some image editing experience, and if I could create an image sequence from this and color correct all those images individually, I'm pretty sure there shouldn't be any flickering.

Comment: @Samoth I didn't have time to do that in blender having little experience with green screen and the necessary post work, I was afraid something might go wrong that would force us to re-record. But I hadn't imagined a simple color correct would introduce all this flickering either.

Comment: Filming a projector is never a good Idea because the image will be updated with a certain frequency and your camera captures your movie with most likely another and even if they would match there will always be interference as you can't match them perfectly in sync manually. I guess the flickering was there before but with the rerender process it just got emphasized.